# Segfault in jukebox example with libspotify 12.1.51 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: spotify, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I get a SIGSEGVs when running the jukebox example (update: spshell as well).  Version details:

libspotify 12.1.51, libc6, arm6t
Raspberry Pi soft float raspbian

gdb output:

jukebox: Rootlist synchronized (21 playlists)
malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x00027f78 ***

Comment: Does the jukebox segfault right after starting up? Or when playing music? Or in reaction to what command?

Comment: It passes authentication, then segfaults right before or as it trys to start downloading/streaming/player.

Comment: I was trying the armsf version because an armhf version wasn't available.  There is now a hard float version:

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/blog/2013/01/22/libspotify-12-hardfloat-beta/